# No download folder created when performing download in cypress on jenkins

Tags: jenkins, directory, download, electron, cypress

I use cypress (6.9.1) on jenkins and want to test downloading a file from a web-app.

As of cypress 6.3.0, #5651 , file download is supported both in browser with GUI and headless browser electron.

But when I start my test in headless electron 87 on Jenkins I get the result that the test has passed successfully but I can't find the downloaded file since there is no download folder with the downloaded file created.

Indeed there is a message `tput. No value for $TERM and no -T specified` but the test passes successfully as described above.
When I do the same test on my local machine on which the same cypress-version (6.9.1) is installed without Jenkins it works fine and I can find the downloaded file in the default download folder.

Has somebody encountered this issue or could say to me why there is no download folder when downloading with cypress on Jenkins?